# How to Check Folder Exits on Sharepoint Document Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, shared-libraries

I want to check Folder exits on Sharepoint Document Library.

- I have a Document Library called `Attachments` there are many Root Folders like this (`CMR_2000`,`CMR_2001`)
- as a example i want to check is `CMR_2000` folder already exits on sharepoint document library ?

How can i do this ??

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows

```
if (SPWeb.GetFolder(folderAbsoluteUrl).Exists)
{
    //Folder Exisits
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

> public static bool CheckFolderExists(SPWeb web, string folderUrl)
>
> ```
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             return web.GetFolder(folderUrl).Exists;
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Call it:

> ```
>         using (var web = new SPSite("http://site").OpenWeb())
>         {
>           var folderExists=  CheckFolderExists(web, "Attachments/CMR_2000");
>         }
> ```